# Adding New attribute in a existing type in Hybris 5.3 is not showing in HMC and HAC

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have added a new attribute in one existing type. my attribute is available in model class and also in jalo classes. 
But when i checked in HMC it is not showing the attribute in admin tab.
As well as in type's XML configuration does not have that attribute in HMC.

steps done by me:
added my attributes in items.xml where other attributes also added earlier.
after this i have run ant clean all and checked the model class and attribute is there in model class.

used below code for adding my attribute in items.xml:

```
<itemtype code="Customer" autocreate="false" generate="false">
            <attributes>
<attribute qualifier="OosFlag" type="java.lang.Boolean">
                    <description>OosFlag</description>
                    <defaultvalue>Boolean.TRUE</defaultvalue>
                    <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="false"/>
                    <persistence type="property"/>
                </attribute>
            </attributes>
            </itemtype>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your type-system in the database. That means you need to do an UPDATE in the admin-console.

The generated classes are only templates. The important point is what in the database stands.

P.S. you should start your attributes always with a lower-case.